# Identify and disable weak cipher suites Windows server 2008 / IIS 7

Tags: ssl, iis-7, windows-server-2008, encryption

i'm asking a question on a subject that is pure chinese to me..sorry in advance

A security scan result prior to the deployment of a web application on windows server 2008 R2 has raised the below message :

> Weak SSL Cipher Suites are Supported
>
> Reconfigure the server to avoid the use of weak cipher suites. The
>   configuration changes are server-specific.
>
> SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5!EXP:!NULL:!LOW:!ADH
>
> For Microsoft Windows Vista, Microsoft Windows 7, and Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2008, remove the cipher suites that were identified as
>   weak from the Supported Cipher Suite list by following these
>   instructions:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930(v=vs.85).aspx

I've tried undertsanding the msdn information but i'm totally lost in there.

first of all I do not undertsand which is the cipher suite that should be removed or disabled.

and then, how am I suppose to run the code given as example to remove a cipher suite?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>

void main()
{

SECURITY_STATUS Status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
  LPWSTR wszCipher = (L"TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA");

Status = BCryptRemoveContextFunction(
            CRYPT_LOCAL,
            L"SSL",
            NCRYPT_SCHANNEL_INTERFACE,
            wszCipher);
}
```

again sorry for total lack of knowledge here!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution was given to me on [Security.StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48325/identify-and-disable-weak-cipher-suites) :

Using "[IIS CRYPTO](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx)" on the server allowed me to visualize the cipher suites and very easily remove the weak ones.